# Warning: function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, return-type

The following code gives the warning below. Can someone please explain why (note the code is not useful as is as I replaced my types with int to make a complete example).

warning: '`MaxEventSize()`' function uses '`auto`' type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]

The idea is to get the maximum size of a particular structure (types go where `int` is).

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T cexMax(T a, T b)
{
    return (a < b) ? b : a;
}

constexpr auto MaxEventSize()
{
    return cexMax(sizeof(int),
           cexMax(sizeof(int),
                    sizeof(int)));
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to tag your question with the name of the language this is.

Comment: This reads like an X-Y problem: You *want* to write a functions that returns `size_t`. However, you *ask* about templates, `auto`, and-what-not. Better stick to KISS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `auto` return type "without trailing return type" is a C++14 feature, so I suppose you're compiling C++11.

Your code is OK with C++14, but for C++11, if you want use `auto` as return type, you need describe the effective return type in this way (caution: pseudocode)

```
auto funcName (args...) -> returnType
```

You know that `sizeof()` returns `std::size_t`, so your example can be corrected as

```
constexpr auto MaxEventSize() -> std::size_t
{
    return cexMax(sizeof(int),
           cexMax(sizeof(int),
                    sizeof(int)));
};
```

or (silly, in this case, but show the use in more complex examples)

```
constexpr auto MaxEventSize() -> decltype( cexMax(sizeof(int),
                                                  cexMax(sizeof(int),
                                                         sizeof(int))) )
{
    return cexMax(sizeof(int),
           cexMax(sizeof(int),
                    sizeof(int)));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have never seen that syntax before although am just in the process of learning C++11/14 upgrades...

Comment: So in c++11, why would I write constexpr auto ..., ratther than constexpr size_t ...?

Comment: I also don't get why use `auto` here.

Comment: @Jack - there is no need of use `auto` here; obviously you can write `constexpr std::size_t MaxEventSize()`. But the answer is under the premise " if you want use `auto` as return type"; I mean: this answer try to explain how to use the `auto` way to indicate the return type.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use template T?
Replace the line

```
constexpr auto MaxEventSize()
```

With

```
template<typename T>constexpr T MaxEventSize()
```

That should work fine with C++11.

Comment: Uhhmmm... the template type `T` can't be deduced (no arguments of type `T`) so, this way, the function must be called explicating the return type. And the return type should be `std::size_t`, so the call should be something as `auto var = MaxEventSize<std::size_t>();`. I suppose could work but, frankly, doesn't seems to me a great idea.